# How to apply CSS to text that is NOT inside a certain tag? just #text! by using R, Selenium

Tags: css, r

```
<div class="nameTitle">AAA
<span>BBB</span></div>
```

I want to extract only "AAA" character or "AAA BBB"

my code

```
  source = remDr$getPageSource()
  text = read_html(source[[1]],encoding='EUC-KR')

 text %>% 
   html_nodes(css='.nameTitle') %>% html_text()
```

and result

```
AAABBB
```

There is no space.

another code

```
 text %>% 
   html_nodes(css='.nameTitle span') %>% html_text()
>>BBB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer because I don't know enough about R, but perhaps you could translate this pure JS snippet to R.

It puts a space at the start of the span, reads the innerText of the whole thing and then restores the span innerHTML.

```js
// function to take a class name and return the innerText with a space before the (first) span element
function spacedText(str) {
  const el = document.querySelector('.' + str);
  const spanEl = el.querySelector('span');
  const temp = spanEl.innerHTML;
  spanEl.innerHTML = ' ' + spanEl.innerHTML;
  const text = el.innerText;
  spanEl.innerHTML = temp;
  return text;
}
console.log(spacedText('nameTitle'));
alert(spacedText('nameTitle'));
```

```html
<div class="nameTitle">AAA
  <span>BBB</span></div>
```